# Post not sending to correct controller method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

Im trying to post to an mvc controller via jQuery.
There is both a HomeController and an OrdersController.  When the post is called, the Orders/LoadFromSearch action method is called, but then the Home/Orders method is called before finally returning the Orders view.  I want to simply return the Orders view from Orders/LoadFromSearch.  What am I missing?  Why am I hitting the Homecontroller?

jQuery post

```
 $.post('/Orders/LoadFromSearch', p)
            .done(function (response, status, jqxhr) {
                //do stuff
        })
        .fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
            alert('oops cant load view');
        })
```

Route setup looks like this:

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Listing", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );         
    }
```

MVC Orders LoadFromSearch

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult LoadFromSearch(string chNo)
{
    ViewBag.SearchNum = chNo;
    return View("Orders");
}
```

Home/Orders

```
public ActionResult Orders() {
    return View;
}
```

[ **update** ]
The jquery post is being triggered on clicking a link in a kendo grid.  Also to add, the views use a Layout template, which I realized as I started stepping through all the way.  In the process of stepping through the _Layout template, thew HomeController gets invoked with the Orders action.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part.  What Im trying to figure out is why the HomeController is getting hit at all?

Comment: What is triggering the jQuery post?

Comment: Is this your entire route configuration including areas and attribute routes? If not, please post it.

Comment: As per @zgood - if you're triggering this from a `<button type='submit'>` `click` handler, then that's your issue.  It'll get the result but also submit which will hit the home controller "*but then the Home/Orders method is called* [as well] ".   Change to `<button type='button'` or handle the `.on("submit"..` rather than "click"

Comment: As it's an ajax request, did you mean to use:  `return PartialView("Orders");` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m, no I didnt, but I just realized that doing an ajax post isnt what I need to do since its going to try to return the view back to the ajax method.  I want to take the user to a different view, so I just need something like window.location